# Adding a table column using jquery and the new column should be the first column

Tags: jquery

Thanks for all yor help. My requrirement is to prepend the column to a row with image. But my image is moving all the columns to the right. How to add image to only matching rows but not moving other columns to right. Iam attaching my screenshot here. Please help me.[image]

Thanks,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dlglobal.dl.com/Admin/IT/operations/Documents/jquery.SPServices-0.5.8.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
//alert("alert test");
/*$Textsql = $("td.ms-vb2:contains('Budakov')"); 
$Textsql.css("background-color", "#461B7E"); */


$().SPServices({
  operation: "GetListItems",
  async: false,  
  listName: "OnCallList",

  completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    //alert(xData.responseXML.xml);
$("#ctl00_m_g_87fe292c_7976_4ad4_bf5c_3c1ecf08b2d8_AdvancedDataGrid tr:first").append("<th></th>");

    $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName=z:row]").each(function() {     

     var TextList=$(this).attr("ows_Title");
     $Textsql = $("td.ms-vb2:contains('" + TextList.toString() + "')");

     $Textsql.parent().prepend("<td class='ms-vb2'><img src='http://dlglobal.dl.com/Admin/IT/operations/PublishingImages/OnCall.png' /></td>");  });
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: You are adding a cell, but I think you should add a row... or add the image to the first cell of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a fixed with on the TD and add it to every row.  Then only populate that TD with the image for the selected rows.  This way that column will always be the width of the image whether or not it is present.